# Why does jQuery make my page jump back to the top after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a general question about jQuery.

I have created few jQuery buttons but the problem that I have is when you scroll half way down the page and you press the button, the page jumps back to top, instead of staying in the middle where the button is??

How can you stop this from happening, as it's frustrating for the user??

Is there any particular reason why it's happening?

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RvHjx/):

```
$(".comment-here").click(function() {
   $(".comment-form").slideToggle('slow');
});

$(".main-btn.orange").click(function(){
   $(".comment-form").slideUp('slow');
});
```

Comment: I'd argue that using a `<button>` instead of an `<a>` is the more proper way to solve this problem. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're not preventing the default event. Since you're clicking on an anchor tag, the default event for `#` is just to jump up to the top of the document.

To prevent this from occurring:

Pass the event into the function, and use preventDefault();

```
$(".comment-here").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".comment-form").slideToggle('slow');
})

$(".main-btn.orange").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".comment-form").slideUp('slow');
})
```

You could also use `return false;` instead, which goes a bit further than just preventing the default event, it will stop events `bubbling` up to `parent` elements.

Comment: "There is no dark side in the moon, really. As a matter of fact it's all dark"

Comment: i used the "return false". My problem is different. I call a javascript to expand the accordion but when it expanded the window also moved to the accordion. What i wanted was that the window will stay where it is while the accordion is expanding. So "return false" is the solution. tnx

Answer (score 2):

Add `return false;` to the click handler of the `<a class="comment-here">`.

Essentially it is not jQuery, but the default browser behaviour that causes this: you clicked a link, it has to navigate to its href, which is... `"#"`, i.e. this page. So there we go back to this page (the top).

Answer (score 0):

Prevent default behaviour of anchor tags:

```
$(".comment-here").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `<a>` tag using `href="#"` which references the current page and pulls you to the top.

I'd recommend the following approaches, instead of the default event prevention mentioned in other answers. Of course those work, but why use an element only to remove it's default functions?

Ergo, use something that is intended for your purpose:

1.) Use a `<button>` instead of `<a>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/RvHjx/7/

2.) If you're dead set on using `<a>`, remove the `href` attribute in your `<a>` tag. This will remove the blue-underlined link styling (the link still functions correctly though), but it's easy to fix with some CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/RvHjx/11/

Comment: removing href from the a tag is not the best practice

Comment: @SlickRemix did you read my post? I did not recommend that, but presented the option if the user was only "dead set" on it.

Comment: @skipper, to be fair I did but still wanted to note that because there are a couple other work arounds, sorry I was so short... one of them I have used for a long time is href="javascript:;" ... beats adding # which always has mixed results as we know and the element structure is kept proper.

Answer (score 0):

Adding javascript:; to your a tags href is the simplest way.

```
<a href="javascript:;">my link</a>
```